# Installing pfx SSL certificate in Tomcat 8.5 on Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, openssl, pfx

I have a wildcard .pfx certificate with its intermediate certificate in p7b/crt format. Those certificates are installed on IIS 8.0. How can I install those certificates in Tomcat 8.0? Tomcat is installed on Windows.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I could do it successfully. As I have mentioned that my certificate was installed on IIS web server on windows with intermediate certificate. So I follow below steps

**Step 1: Create a Microsoft Management Console (MMC) Snap-in for managing certificates**

1. Access the Search menu. In the search box, type **mmc**
2. From the **Microsoft Management Console (MMC)**, click  **File > Add/Remove Snap-in**
3. From the list of snap-ins, select **Certificates**
4. Click **Add**
5. Select **Computer Account**
6. Click **Next**
7. Select **Local Computer** (the computer this console is running on)
8. Click **Finish**
9. In the Add/Remove Snap-in window, click **OK**
10. Save these console settings for future use

**Step 2: Export/ Back Up the certificate**

1. Open the Certificates (Local Computer) snap-in you added > select **Personal** > **Certificates**
2. Right-click certificate name > select **All Tasks** > **Export**.
3. The Certificate Export Wizard opens > click **Next**
4. Select **Yes, export the private key** > click **Next**
5. Select **Personal Information Exchange**
6. Ensure to check only ***Include all certificates in the certificate path if possible*** > click **Next**
7. Enter and confirm a password > click **Next**
8. Choose a file name and location for the export file > click **Next**
9. Click **Finish**

**Step 3:  Configure PKCS12 (.pfx) file on Tomcat server**

1. Open %TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml in XML or text editor
2. Find the following lines: (**In my case, I could not find below lines, So I directly jump to point 4 and add whole tag in my server.xml and change keystorefile and keystorePassword**)

   `<!-- <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" /> -->`
3. Delete the comment markers at the beginning of the code (`<!--`) and at the end of the code (`-->`)
4. Immediately after sslProtocol="TLS" and before />,  add the following attributes:

   `<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/path/to/mycert.pfx" keystoreType="PKCS12" keystorePass="your_PKCS12_password" />`
5. Save server.xml
6. Restart Tomcat

Hope it will help somebody :)

Comment: I can confirm that this config also work on Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 4):

Please convert the PFX file into a Tomcat compatible format . The command is given below

[image]

```
Keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore tomcat.jks -deststoretype jks
```

The tomcat.jks file directives can be provided in the server.xml file of tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat can use a PFX (PKCS12) file just fine, there is no need to convert to JKS

Comment: Tomcat 8.5.71 accepts PFX without a problem.

Comment: tomcat 7 even, can use pfx